# uniqueIdentifier is called in chartboost

Tags: iphone, ios6, uniqueidentifier, chartboost

In my app I use new **Chartboost sdk 3.2.1**
But still while i checked it for **uniqueIdentifier** it will give me error.

Please help me to solve it to submit app on appstore.

I just Find the class that use the UDID by

(terminal in the project directory)

```
find . | grep -v .svn  | grep "\.a" | grep -v "\.app" | xargs grep uniqueIdentifier
```

and get this in terminal

**Binary file ./libChartboost.a matches**

Comment: Are you sure you the correct Library, because there blog states that 3.2 does not contain the uniqueIdentifier: http://blog.chartboost.com/post/48622589171/sdk-3-2-is-out. Be sure the clean your build.

Comment: yes i check it twice.And that's why i m confuse where is my mistake?

Comment: recently i used the new chartboost SDK from chartboost website to ignore uniqueIdentifier and its works perfectly for me.

Comment: @TapanNathvani :Its working grate with me also.But when i used terminal to check it it will throw me error.

Comment: @TapanNathvani :can you try this in terminal?

Comment: ya i also checked it in terminal, and i didnt get anything... and if your app is ready to upload then just try to upload from application loader, it will generate error if your code using uniqueIdentifier.

Comment: @TapanNathvani :just for test know i check downloaded chartboost sdk and test with same in terminal and it also give me same error

Comment: did you replace new charboost files with existing chartboost library files that you used in past ? because i jst replace the new files with existing one and it works for me.

Comment: @TapanNathvani: i delete all old one files and add new one as describe in Chartboost blog.

Comment: ohk.. now i cant help you because i cant understand whats happening there.. but my suggestion is that why dont you try to upload app via application loader, so it will generate an error while uplaoding regarding to uniqueIdentifier if your code used that.

Comment: @TapanNathvani :I upload it via organiser and it will return uniqueIdentifier called.And then after googling i find this command-line to check.
Any way thanks for you rply

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31192/discussion-between-tapan-nathvani-and-harin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After wasting 1.5 days finally I got solution and my application is now submitted to App Store.

After play a lot with terminal, finally I used this command

```
grep -r 'uniqueIdentifier' * .[!.]*
```

It will **Search for a string inside all files in the current directory and 
 recursively searches dirs and files.(also search for hidden)**

so after that I found in terminal

1. There are some extra classes in my project directory which I never
   used in my xcode project and they are called **uniqueIdentifier**
2. Also **Binary file libChartboost.a matches**
3. Binary file RevMobAds.framework/RevMobAds matches
   Binary file RevMobAds.framework/Versions/A/RevMobAds matches
   Binary file RevMobAds.framework/Versions/Current/RevMobAds matches

Now, for Problem 1 I removed extra unusable classes

for Problem 2 **Chartboost**

1. Drag & drop Chartboost in project
2. **Uncheck** -Copy items into destination group's folder(if needed)
3. **Select** -Create groups for any added folders
4. Add to targets

and For Problem 3 **RevMobAds**

1. Drag & drop RevMobAds.framework in project
2. **Uncheck** -Copy items into destination group's folder(if needed)
3. **Select** -Create folder references for any added folders
4. Add to targets

**I USED UPDATED THIRD-PARTY LIBRARY BOTH TIME.**

Strange but it will works and now my app is submitted.Hope it will help someone.

**Note**:Please tell me why Chartboost and RebMobsads.framework will  give me error while i **checked** -Copy items into destination group's folder(if needed) in my project.(If anyone have any idea)

Comment: "if needed" most likely it did not overwrite the existing files.  The "Create folder references for any added folders" will create new folders with the latest version of libraries copied over.

Comment: I have done the above for chartboost but the app is not uploading due to the same error? I am using charboost version 3.2.2.

Comment: @MayurShrivas : find . | grep -v .svn  | grep "\.a" | grep -v "\.app" | xargs grep uniqueIdentifier  use this to find error

or There are some extra classes in your project directory which you never used in your xcode project and they are called uniqueIdentifier ?

Comment: @Harin I have tried that but there are no such files which are using "uniqueIdentifier" in my project? The above command doesn't gives me any matches.

Comment: @MayurShrivas : Ok well, so have you find any useless file which are not include in your project but still remain in your Project Folder? Check every folder.In my case this is also effect me.