# ios app rejected due to charboost

Tags: ios, chartboost

My ios application was rejected automatically by the app loader and itunes connect.
I sent an email to chartboost, it says some of their partners experience this issue.
and send me a link to follow the steps.
[uniqueIdentifier is called in chartboost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16916309/uniqueidentifier-is-called-in-chartboost)

Upon trying out the command within the project, only chartboost sdk is detected with the function name.
I have follow the steps in the link, but the application is still rejected.
The charboost sdk in question is 3.2.1, the latest as if 2nd of Oct 2013.
Any idea what other issues can it be?

Comment: So, did this grep -r 'uniqueIdentifier' * .[!.]* find anything?

Comment: the search on Chartboost sdk results in matches. I have emailed them and have let them know about it. They replied saying their engineers ensured that they are no longer using the codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having the same issue now as well. Email sent to Chartboost too hopefully they [fix it soon](http://thechocolatelabapps.com/) http://thechocolatelabapps.com/